# How would I pass value inside data binding in Typescript/ Angular mat Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, typescript2.0

Main Goal: generate a table based on the JSON data

```
 <mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="carrierRates" [dataSource]="carrierRates">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let columnName of columnsList" matColumnDef="{{columnName}}">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{columnName}}</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let itemRate">
                {{itemRate.$columnName}}
            </mat-cell>
            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
        </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsList;"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsList;"></mat-row>
        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="columnsList;"></mat-footer-row>

    </mat-table>
```

Question 1:
How will I run two for loops one to read the column list and one to read the data source?

Question 2:
How would I pass the columnName value in this line
`{{itemRate.$columnName}}`

FYI: columnName is the list of KEY of JSON data

```
{"planId":"abcd",
"rateAreaId":"lmpo",
"singleMonthly":0,
"twoPeopleMonthly":0,
"familyMonthly":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to execute 2 foor loops but you should define only templates for columns and rows.

Each column definition should be given a unique name and contain the content for its header and row cells. Here's a simple column definition with the name `planId`. The header cell contains the text "*Plan ID*" and each row cell will render the `planId` property of each row's data.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="planId">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Plan ID</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let itemRate"> {{itemRate.planId}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

and so on for the rest of the columns names/values.

2. Your column names are `planId`, `rateAreaId`, `singleMonthly`, `twoPeopleMonthly`, `familyMonthly`. This means that in your component file you should create a variable `columnList` that contains the list of the columns you want to render, like the following:

`columnList = [planId, rateAreaId, singleMonthly, twoPeopleMonthly, familyMonthly];`

Then, as you did, add `mat-header-row` and `mat-row` to the content of your `mat-table` and provide your `columnList` as inputs.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsList"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsList"></tr>
```

**Note**: that this list of columns provided to the rows can be in any order, not necessarily the order in which you wrote the column definitions. Also, you do not necessarily have to include every column that was defined in your template.

This means that by changing your column list provided to the rows, you can easily re-order and include/exclude columns dynamically.

Anyway, I just copied some part of the comprehensive [documentation of angular material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) ;)

Comment: Thank You. Really appreciate the help.